# Add minimap to react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I need to have minimap in react-native-maps to show the level of zoom and the place that user is observing the tile. You can see the mini map in the left bottom of the map as below:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<MapView
                onRegionChangeStart={() => setIsZooming(true)}
                onRegionChangeComplete={() => setIsZooming(false)}
                provider={'google'} // Prevents map tiles from loading
                maximumZ={19}
                mapType={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'none' : 'standard'}
                minimumZ={2}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                showsUserLocation={false} // Hide user location marker
                customMapStyle={customMapStyle} // Apply the custom map style here
                style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
                <UrlTile
                  /**
                   * The url template of the tile server. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
                   * For example, http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
                   */
                  urlTemplate={TILE_URL}
                  zIndex={-1000}
                  /**
                   * The maximum zoom level for this tile overlay. Corresponds to the maximumZ setting in
                   * MKTileOverlay. iOS only.
                   */
                  shouldReplaceMapContent={true}
                  flipY={false}
                  /**
                   * flipY allows tiles with inverted y coordinates (origin at bottom left of map)
                   * to be used. Its default value is false.
                   */
                />
                {/* Render your markers */}
                {showPositionMarker.map(marker => (
                  <Marker
                    key={marker.id}
                    coordinate={{
                      latitude: marker.position.lat,
                      longitude: marker.position.lng,
                    }}
                  />
                ))}
              </MapView>
            </View>
```

Is there any standard way to do that?